# Can’t get text item of variable

Tags: applescript

I want to get the task id out of a variable in Apple Script.

Tyme2 got an error: Can’t get text item 2 of task id "AF7AA1C5-F10B-4CFD-97E5-9428CADC9649-1285-000007F1BAB4FE40" of project id "2E97F048-CB5E-4F8B-8DFB-139D39BFD4C7-1285-000003A297D9D970".

Tryed code:

1. `set taskId to the first item of taskProject`

   - **Result for log**
     (*taskid of task id AF7AA1C5-F10B-4CFD-97E5-9428CADC9649-1285-000007F1BAB4FE40 of project id 2E97F048-CB5E-4F8B-8DFB-139D39BFD4C7-1285-000003A297D9D970*)
2. `set taskId to text item 2 of taskProject`

   - **Result:** above error message
3. Elaborate the type via:
   `return properties of taskProject`

   - **Result:** {timedPlannedDuration:0.0, relatedCategoryID:"", dueDate:missing value, class:task, mileageKilometerRate:0.0, timedRoundingMinutes:1, timedRoundingMethod:1, fixedRate:0.0, taskType:"timed", completedDate:missing value, timedHourlyRate:0.0, completed:false, fixedQuantity:0, relatedProjectID:"2E97F048-CB5E-4F8B-8DFB-139D39BFD4C7-1285-000003A297D9D970", id:"2887FB44-D3D6-45BF-9137-00A311E47424-1210-000000DBBD0298A9", name:" (id of taskProject)
     ", relatedTaskID:""}

Comment: `item` and `text item` are two completely different things. Please elaborate of what type `task id` is and what the expected result is.

Comment: in the properties listed-do you see the info you need to get?

Comment: the info I would need is `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of task id, this should work if task id  is of type text (but it might fail, it's hard to read the structure of taskProject from what you wrote)

```
set taskID to ((task id of taskProject) as text)
```

If it doesn't work please add the result of this line to the question:

```
return properties of taskProject
```

Edit:

If you list the properties you can always access them by their key. The key in your case is "id". access it like this:

```
set taskID to ((id of taskProject) as text)
```

or

```
set taskID to ((taskProject's id) as text)
```

Sometimes keys/variable names are reserved by the system. If the above fails try it like this

```
set taskID to ((|id| of taskProject) as text)
```